# Reorder rows in R dataframe by column value

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe called `tab12` that look like this:

```
df <- structure(list(sector = c("Public", "Private", "Other"), mean = c(340L, 
125L, 654L), median = c(876L, 543L, 234L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

sector  mean    median
Public  340     876
Private 125     543
Other   654     234
```

I need to reorder the rows so that the order is "Other", "Public", "Private". I know I can do this by index (e.g, [c(3, 1, 2), ] but is there a way to do this by using the values of the sector column ("Public", "Private" and "Other")?

I have tried:

`tab12 <- tab12$Sector[c("Other", "Public", "Private")]`

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`character` vectors (like your `sector` column) will by default be sorted alphabetically if you order them. You can convert them to a `factor`-class categorical vector which you can define a custom order, and then sort.

If you like `dplyr`:

```
tab12 %>%
  mutate(Sector = factor(Sector, levels = c("Other", "Public", "Private")) %>%
  arrange(Sector)
```

If you prefer base R:

```
tab12$Sector = factor(tab12$Sector, levels = c("Other", "Public", "Private"))
tab12 = tab12[order(tab12$Sector), ]
```

I prefer encoding a custom ordering like this into a `factor` rather than just re-ordering the rows for a few reasons:

- It generalizes nicely to other functions (e.g., plot axes, legends, modeling)
- It works whether you have one or multiple of each value

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `match`:

```r
df[match(c("Other", "Public", "Private"), df$sector),]
#>    sector mean median
#> 3   Other  654    234
#> 1  Public  340    876
#> 2 Private  125    543
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We could transform to factor class and relevel, then use `arrange`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(sector = factor(sector, levels = c("Other", "Public", "Private"))) %>% 
  arrange(sector)

   sector mean median
1   Other  654    234
2  Public  340    876
3 Private  125    543
```